# code analysis to identify all changes between two commits which inflence a particular line of code or variable

Tags: c, git, analysis, code-analysis

I have two versions of source code which contain a long list (500 or so) of code changes (unfortunately no code history available). I'd like to segment out any changes which have or may have an impact on a particular variable XYZ. The end goal would be to be able to run and compare results of the code with all code updates, with a part of the updates not affecting XYZ, and with none of the updates.

Is there a way to run, for example, a sort of code analysis to identify which lines of code will influence a particular variable or line of code, then automagically segment out these changes and create a patch? Id like to end up with a sort of intermediate commit between the two versions I currently have.

The code is written in C,
I am using git to track my own history,
the code is compiled in visual studio 2019.

Comment: Let's say you have version A(old) and version B(new) of your code.
Wouldn't it be a straight forward way of solving this, the "stupid" way, to search for every occurrence of the variable xyz in version B which is not in A and work with that?

Comment: @josepchappa, it's not just the variable itself, its all the functions and related variables which can affect its value.

Comment: The first step of the process would be the same though, no? It's to dentify all occurrences of variable xyz. Then determine in what kind of operation variable xyz is used and proceed for each case. Like say you have `int xyz = 5`, then somewhere in the code you have `xyz = someFunc()` and somewhere else you have `int somevar = xyz + 123`. If some functions and related variables can affect xyz, then it will be definitely called somewhere in the code. Either directly accessed or indirectly as a function parameter or used in some other operations. Either way you will need to call xyz by its name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any software which does this, because in most programming languages, it's nontrivial.  For example, if you take a pointer to that variable in function `f`, then any function which `f` calls, directly or indirectly, can be affected by that variable and can potentially modify it (even if in ways which are not strictly defined behavior).  That's because any of those functions could accept a pointer (possibly cast to another type, or to an integer).  Similarly, if that function takes a pointer value or returns non-void, any of the callers may be able to modify that value (again, through various casts).

If you limit yourself to things which are well defined by the C standard, the scope is a bit smaller, but many nontrivial programs exhibit some undefined behavior and such a tool would be completely unusable for any sort of systems programming.  It would still be quite difficult in that case.

This might be slightly easier in a language like Rust, which has hard restrictions on mutability and references, but even there, I suspect your problem is likely, in the general case, to come down to solving the halting problem or at least be extremely difficult to solve.  Your specific code may be much simpler, of course.